# generate fixed number of rows in a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Not able to word the question properly, so couldn't search what I want. All I need is a dummy table with a single column of say guids, which I use it for some other purposes. Without actually writing same `insert .. newID()` n times, wondering if there is an elegant solution.

Similar question would be how do I populate a blank table with a int column with say 1-n numbers.

```
Row1: 1
Row2: 2
.......
Row100:100
```

Comment: Take a look at this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041163/inserting-n-number-of-records-with-t-sql

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1393951/65223 about numbers tables

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This method is blisteringly fast. If you need to generate a numbers table from nothing, it's probably the "best" means available.

```sql
WITH
t0(i) AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0), --             2 rows
t1(i) AS (SELECT 0 FROM t0 a, t0 b),    --             4 rows
t2(i) AS (SELECT 0 FROM t1 a, t1 b),    --            16 rows
t3(i) AS (SELECT 0 FROM t2 a, t2 b),    --           256 rows
--t4(i) AS (SELECT 0 FROM t3 a, t3 b),  --        65,536 rows
--t5(i) AS (SELECT 0 FROM t4 a, t4 b),  -- 4,294,967,296 rows

n(i) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) FROM t3)
SELECT i FROM n WHERE i BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```

Regarding performance:

- Using SQL Server 2022, on a Xeon box from 2016, with `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` to measure query time I got these numbers:

  - (With `t4` and `t5` commented-out), it generates 256 rows in "0ms".
  - (With `t4` uncommented) it generates 65,536 rows in 53ms.
  - (With `t5` uncommented in an `INSERT FROM`) it generated and inserted 4bn rows to a `TABLE` on-disk in about 65 minutes.

    - That's 66 million rows per minute, or about a million rows per second, *nice!*

Explanation:

- The first CTE, `t0` generates 2 rows.
- Each subsequent CTE performs a `CROSS JOIN` of the previous CTE; a `CROSS JOIN` is a [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) which effectively *squares* the number of rows in each CTE step.

  - So having `t0` through `t3` means performing the Cartesian product three times, thus generating [image: 256 rows == 2 squared, squared, squared again] rows.
  - `SELECT 0 FROM t0 a, t0 b` is the same thing as `SELECT 0 FROM t0 AS a CROSS JOIN t0 AS b`.

Note that the results start at `1` and not `0` because `ROW_NUMBER()` starts at `1`. To start at `0` do `SELECT ( i - 1 ) FROM n` in the outermost query.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call 2.7 milliseconds per execution "blisteringly fast" compared to 3.1 milliseconds for other, simpler variations on this page, but ok (don't forget to generate the GUID when testing too). :-)

Answer (score 13):

Instead of a recursive CTE, I recommend a set-based approach from any object you know already has more than 100 rows.

```
--INSERT dbo.newtable(ID, GUID)
SELECT TOP (100) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]), NEWID()
  FROM sys.all_columns ORDER BY [object_id];
```

For plenty of other ideas, see this series:

- http://www.sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-1
- http://www.sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-2
- http://www.sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-3

In newer versions (SQL Server 2022 and modern versions of Azure SQL Database / Managed Instance), you can use the new [`GENERATE_SERIES()` function](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/generate-series-to-build-a-set/):

```
SELECT value FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 100);
```

Or on 2016+, you can trick `STRING_SPLIT()` into generating 100 rows from a string of 99 commas (or any character, really):

```
SELECT value = rn FROM 
(
  SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID)
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLICATE(',', 99), ',')
) AS x;
```

And if you need more than 8,000 values:

```
SELECT value = rn FROM 
(
  SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID)
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLICATE(CONVERT(varchar(max),','),79999), ',')
) AS x;
```

These all get around the need to have an existing table with enough rows to match your sequence needs or to be able to access system/catalog views.

Comment: FWIW, in a brand new empty database in SQL Server 2022 the `sys.all_columns` view contains **12,216** rows - so if you want to generate more rows you can do a `CROSS JOIN` on itself to generate 149,230,656 rows.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it recursively.

For numbers, f.ex.:

```
WITH r AS (
    SELECT 1 AS n
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1 FROM r WHERE n+1<=100
)
SELECT * FROM r
```

Comment: Won't work for 101 rows and more - default CTE nesting limit

Answer (score 3):

One way;

```
;with guids( i, guid ) as
(
    select 1 as i, newid() 
        union all
    select i + 1, newid() 
        from guids
        where i < 100
)

select guid from guids option (maxrecursion 100)
```

Comment: maxrecursion 0 also works as no limit (max being 32,767)

Answer (score 2):

Just adding this as it wasn't listed:

A quick way to get 10 rows:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        ORDER BY N1.N) 
        , LOWER(NEWID())
    FROM   (VALUES(1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) AS N1(N)          -- 10
```

If you want it to be based on a variable:

```
DECLARE  @N int = 10;
WITH Numbers(number)
     AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                ORDER BY N1.N)
         FROM   (VALUES(1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) AS N1(N)          -- 10
                CROSS JOIN(VALUES(1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) AS N2(N)-- 100  
                --CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS N3 (N)   -- 1,000
                --CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS N4 (N)   -- 10,000
                --CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS N5 (N) -- 100,000
                -- Etc....
)
     SELECT *
          , LOWER(NEWID())
     FROM   Numbers
     WHERE  number <= @N;
```