# SQL Server query doesn't return all stores

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running around in circles and have been doing so in the last hours.

I'm doing a select in a table where have all stock of each store and I'm filtering by product id. What i need is: have a list of all stores even if I have no data for that store, but the select only returns 4 stores or less.

Here's  an example:

That's the query:

```
select 
    store_id, product_id, start_date, quantity 
from 
    stock 
where 
    product_id = 407214
```

That's the result:

```
store_id | product_id |       start_date      | quantity |
    2    |   407214   |  2015-05-26 08:32:53  |    10    |
    3    |   407214   |  2015-03-16 12:10:00  |    25    |
    4    |   407214   |  2015-01-06 11:45:15  |    16    |
    7    |   407214   |  2015-05-14 00:00:00  |    8     |
```

And that's what I want:

```
store_id | product_id |       start_date      | quantity |
    1    |    NULL    |          NULL         |   NULL   |
    2    |   407214   |  2015-05-26 08:32:53  |    10    |
    3    |   407214   |  2015-03-16 12:10:00  |    25    |
    4    |   407214   |  2015-01-06 11:45:15  |    16    |
    5    |    NULL    |          NULL         |   NULL   |
    6    |    NULL    |          NULL         |   NULL   |
    7    |   407214   |  2015-05-14 00:00:00  |    8     |
```

I would really need a help, it's driving me crazy!!

Comment: Add this to your where: OR product_id IS NULL

Comment: Nothing guys, returns the same results

Comment: even if i do select * from stock where product_id = 407214 or product_id is null , it return the same result

Comment: If adding `product_id IS NULL` to your where clause doesn't fix it, then those values probably aren't `NULL`s

Comment: Do you have a table that has all the store_id's you want in it?

Comment: Yes Tab, but i did left, right, outer, full joins and no one returned me the result that i want

Comment: I'm confused - why would you be using a join?  You're selecting data from a single table according to your post.  What are the results when you do `SELECT store_id, product_id, start_date, quantity FROM  store`?  If there's another table involved it should be included in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the solution depends on your db structure

if `stock` table only contains available products, you need `left join` of tables `stores` and `stock`

```
select 
  s.id as store_id, 
  st.product_id, 
  st.start_date, 
  st.quantity 
from 
stores s
left join stock st on s.Id = st.store_id and st.product_id = 407214
```

Comment: Ash, i tried to do like you posted but the result still the same

Comment: @AlanCarvalhoChiganças, note that i removed `where` clause and moved filter by product_id into join condition. did you do the same?

Comment: Where are you getting that there's a stores table?

Comment: @DanField, `store_id` is likely a foreign key, so i made an assumption that db structure includes table `stores`

Answer (score 3):

Add `OR product_id IS NULL` to the `WHERE` clause

Comment: Just a suggestion, but maybe explain why that fixes the issue.  It's likely not obvious o the asker.

Comment: Nothing guys, returns the same results

Comment: Is that an actual NULL (meaning the column is nullable and is considered emtpy) or are you putting the word 'NULL' into the column?

Comment: even if i do select * from stock where product_id = 407214 or product_id is null , it return the same result

Comment: Then update  your question.  This query would produce the correct results as specified in your original question.

Comment: ...I would never expect this to work, because you're not supposed to use null values in keys.  The design of the table runs counter to data (probably) being stored this way.

Answer (score 0):

`Is null` will return the rows where there is no value. The `or` in the `where` clause is for condition. If the specific row means one of these conditions.

```
select store_id, product_id, start_date, quantity 
     from stock where 
          product_id = 407214 OR Product_id iS null
```

Or your null is a string ?

```
 select store_id, product_id, start_date, quantity 
     from stock where 
          product_id = 407214 OR Product_id like null
```

Or maybe you are inputting product_id as null you can try this:

```
select store_id, product_id, start_date, quantity 
    from stock where 
       product_id = 407214 OR Product_id = null
```

Or maybe if you want everything, remove the  `where` clause but you order by product_id: (maybe this is what you mean)

```
select store_id, product_id, start_date, quantity from stock order by product_id
```

Comment: ...I would never expect this to work, because you're not supposed to use null values in keys.  The design of the table runs counter to data (probably) being stored this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
select store_id, product_id, start_date, quantity from stock where product_id = 407214 or product_id = null
```

Comment: ...I would never expect this to work, because you're not supposed to use null values in keys.  The design of the table runs counter to data (probably) being stored this way.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing how to [generate fixed number of rows in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264498/generate-fixed-number-of-rows-in-a-table) you can:

```
--select 5 as store_id, 407214 as product_id, 3 as start_date, 3 as quantity into stock

DECLARE @maxStoreId int
SELECT 
    @maxStoreId = MAX(store_id) 
FROM 
    stock;

WITH r AS (
    SELECT 1 AS n
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1 FROM r WHERE n+1<=@maxStoreId
)
SELECT 
    r.n as store_id, product_id, start_date, quantity  
FROM 
    r left outer join stock on  r.n = stock.store_id
WHERE 
    product_id = 407214 or product_id is null

--drop table stock
```

Comment: If you have a stores table, @ASh solution is better

Comment: sbiz, i tried to do like you posted but the result still the same. the column n presents the same values that store_id

Comment: Try now. I modified the code so r.n acts as the store_id. Keep in mind that the store_ids are generated and may not exist in your data model

Comment: You should put the `product_id` comparisons in the `ON` clause, which would allow you to get rid of `OR product_id IS NULL`